# key on unknown named Element

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a XML-Structure like this:

```
<Rootname>  
<FIRST a="1" otherhattrs="whatever">  
</FIRST>
<GROUPB a="b2" b="12" c="b456">
    <SET NR="01">
        <ENTRY type="10" otherhattr="whatever"/>
    </SET>
    <SET NR="02">
        <ENTRY type="10" otherhattr="whatever"/>
        <ENTRY type="10" otherhattr="whatever"/>
        <ENTRY type="20" otherhattr="whatever"/>
    </SET>
</GROUPB>
<GROUPC a="c3" b="23">
    <SET NR="01">
        <ENTRY type="10" otherhattr="whatever"/>
    </SET>
    <SET NR="02">
        <ENTRY type="10" otherhattr="whatever"/>
        <ENTRY type="30" otherhattr="whatever"/>
        <ENTRY type="50" otherhattr="whatever"/>
    </SET>
</GROUPC>
<GROUPD a="d4" b="34">
    <SET NR="02">
        <ENTRY type="10" otherhattr="whatever"/>
    </SET>
    <SET NR="03">
        <ENTRY type="50" otherhattr="whatever"/>
        <ENTRY type="50" otherhattr="whatever"/>
        <ENTRY type="60" otherhattr="whatever"/>
    </SET>
</GROUPD>
</Rootname>
```

My Result has to be this:

```
1|b2|b456|01|10|1
1|b2|b456|02|10|2
1|b2|b456|02|20|1
1|c3|23|01|10|1
1|c3|23|02|10|1
1|c3|23|02|30|1
1|c3|23|02|50|1
1|d4|34|02|10|1
1|d4|34|03|50|2
1|d4|34|03|60|1
```

The logic is a little bit complex, but i will describe:
There are different Groups(GROUP) all belonging to the element FIRST. So first of all I need the attributes "a" of them(FIRST and GROUP) and attribute "b" of the GROUP. Second step is I need the number(NR) of the SET. Third and last step is I need the "type" of the ENTRY and the quantity of Entries (ENTRY) with the same type in the same SET.

Now there is an Exception:
GROUPB is a special one, if there is an attribute "c", I don't need "b" but "c".

I thought I could solve my main-problem (the number of entries with same type in same set) by a key with {GROUP-attribute "a", SET-attribute "NR" and ENTRY-attribute "type"} but I'm frustrated, getting no keys or anything back.

My last working XSL was this, with the problem that it sorts out ENTRIES in other GROUPS and SETS:

```
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="ISO-8859-15" indent="no"/>

<xsl:template match="/">

    <xsl:variable name="a" select="/*/FIRST/@a"/>

    <xsl:if test="string($a) != ''">
        <xsl:for-each select="/*/GROUPC[string(@a) != ''] | /*/GROUPB[string(@a) != '']| /*/GROUPD[string(@a) != '']">
            <xsl:sort select="@a"/>
            <xsl:variable name="out">
                <xsl:apply-templates select=".">
                    <xsl:with-param name="a" select="$a"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:value-of select="$out"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>    

<xsl:template match="GROUPB">
    <xsl:param name="a"/>

    <xsl:variable name="begin">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="@c">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat($a, '|', @a,'|',@c,'|')"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat($a, '|', @a,'|',@b,'|')"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="result">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="SET/ENTRY">
            <xsl:with-param name="begin" select="$begin"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="$result" />
</xsl:template>    

<xsl:template match="GROUPC">
    <xsl:param name="a"/>

    <xsl:variable name="begin">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($a, '|', @a,'|',@b,'|')"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="result">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="SET/ENTRY">
            <xsl:with-param name="begin" select="$begin"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="$result" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="GROUPD">
    <xsl:param name="a"/>

    <xsl:variable name="begin">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($a, '|', @a,'|',@b,'|')"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="result">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="SET/ENTRY">
            <xsl:with-param name="begin" select="$begin"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="$result" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:key name="art" match="ENTRY" use="@type"/>

<xsl:template match="SET">
    <xsl:param name="begin"/>
    <xsl:variable name="nummer">
        <xsl:value-of select="@NR"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:for-each select="ENTRY[generate-id() = generate-id(key('art',@type))]">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat($begin, $nummer, '|', @type, '|', count(../ENTRY[@type=current()/@type]))" /><xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

A last sentence, there could be GROUPS and SETS and ENTRIES without one of the wanted attributes, these ones shouldn't appear in the result.

Anybody can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got somewhat confused by your description, and I could not follow your code at all. I *think* you want to do something like this:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:key name="k" match="ENTRY" use="concat(generate-id(..), '|', @type)"/>

<xsl:template match="/Rootname">
    <xsl:variable name="first-a" select="FIRST/@a" />
    <xsl:for-each select="*/SET/ENTRY[count(. | key('k', concat(generate-id(..), '|', @type))[1]) = 1]">
        <xsl:value-of select="$first-a"/>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="../../@a"/>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="../../@c">
                <xsl:value-of select="../../@c"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="../../@b"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="../@NR"/>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="@type"/>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="count(key('k', concat(generate-id(..), '|', @type)))"/>       
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi, I was puzzling around myself, but your solution is much better than mine was going to be. So +1 from my side! That's great example for a key usage!

Comment: One question: Would you please explain to me the `count(. | key(...` How is the dot-pipe-key to interpret? Thx!

Comment: @Shnugo It's another form of Muenchian grouping -see: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

Comment: Thx, I've just read this and hope I got it... Great explanation of Muenchian Grouping. Added to my Links list...

Comment: Wow, thank you very much michael, this is the xsl i was looking for